# How to find the minimum voltage Dᵣ must be able to support?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, dc-dc-converter

Is voltage V<sub>in</sub> the same experienced at DZ1? I'm trying to work out the minimum voltage at D<sub>r</sub> and the equation says it's n multiplied by the DZ1 voltage. This is a dual-switch forward converter.

[image: dual switch]

[image: forward]

Comment: trying to work out the minimum voltage Dr can support?  i was thinking N x V reset

Comment: Single* switch forward converter?

Comment: you're right. im asking about this sorry. i want to know the minimum voltage that diode Dr must be able to support. i though it was Vin x n where n is n2/n1

Comment: What is VDZ1? I don't see anything with that label marked on the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

The primary referred reset voltage of a two-switch forward converter is Vin (plus two diodes, to be precise).  The reset voltage of a one-switch converter with zener clamp, is the zener voltage (plus a diode drop).

The secondary referred voltage is \$n = \frac{N_2}{N_1}\$ times the primary voltage.  To be precise, add Df forward voltage afterwards as well.